# Determine number of cores in configure.ac

Tags: autotools, configure

Is there any `ax_*` in autotool to get the number of cores online at configure (`./configure`) time?

Comment: The Autotools do not ship with a macro for counting the number of cores in the build system.  (And if they did, its name would not start with `AX_`, as that's reserved for extensions.)  You can probably find a third-party macro to do what you want, maybe at [the Autoconf Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/), but software and tool recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - just so: [`ax_count_cpus`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_count_cpus.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Autoconf Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) have a lot of useful macros.

You can use [`AX_COUNT_CPUS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_count_cpus.html) for counting number of available CPU cores (not number of CPUs!).

However use this macro results with caution! For example, some Debian automated build machines can have 128 CPU cores, which may drive you app crazy if you try to use them all.

I do not recommend also to use detected number to enforce number of parallel jobs in `make` as build of your application maybe launched inside another build and number of jobs must be controlled by `make` internal mechanism (job tokens).